# In Ruby, in a method defined in class << self, why can't a constant defined on the superclass be access without self?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand Ruby singletons and class inheritance better. I read everywhere that

```
def self.method_name; end`
```

is equivalent to

```
class << self
  def method_name; end
end
```

But if that were true, then I would expect `print_constant_fails` to work, but it doesn't. What is going on here?

```
class SuperExample
  A_CONSTANT = "super example constant"
end

class SubExample < SuperExample
  def self.print_constant_works_1
    puts A_CONSTANT
  end
  class << self
    def print_constant_works_2
      puts self::A_CONSTANT
    end
    def print_constant_fails
      puts A_CONSTANT
    end
  end
end
```

```
pry(main)> SubExample.print_constant_works_1
super example constant

pry(main)> SubExample.print_constant_works_2
super example constant

pry(main)> SubExample.print_constant_fails
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:SubExample>::A_CONSTANT
from (pry):13:in `print_constant_fails'
```

Comment: Add end keyword to  close the SubExample class properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have encountered a common Ruby gotcha - constant lookup.

The most important concept in constant lookup is `Module.nesting` (unlike in method lookup, where the primary starting point is `self`). This method gives you the current module nesting which is directly used by the Ruby interpreter when resolving the constant token. The only way to modify the nesting is to use keywords `class` and `module` and it only includes modules and classes for which you used that keyword:

```
class A
  Module.nesting #=> [A]

  class B
    Module.nesting #=> [A::B, A]
  end
end

class A::B
  Module.nesting #=> [A::B] sic! no A
end
```

In meta programming, a module or class can be defined dynamically using `Class.new` or `Module.new` - this does not affect nesting and is an extremely common cause of bugs (ah, also worth mentioning - constants are defined on the first module of Module.nesting):

```
module A
  B = Class.new do
    VALUE = 1
  end

  C = Class.new do
    VALUE = 2
  end
end

A::B::VALUE #=> uninitialized constant A::B::VALUE
A::VALUE #=> 2
```

The above code will generate two warnings: one for double initialization of constant A::VALUE and a second for reassigning the constant.

If it looks like "I'd never do that" - this also applies to all the constants defined within `RSpec.describe` (which internally calls Class.new), so if you define a constant within your rspec tests, they are most certainly global (unless you explicitly stated the module it is to be defined in with `self::`)

Now let's get back to your code:

```
class SubExample < SuperExample
  puts Module.nesting.inspect #=> [SubExample]

  class << self
    puts Module.nesting.inspect #=> [#<Class:SubExample>, SubExample]
  end
end
```

When resolving the constant, the interpreter first iterates over all the modules in `Module.nesting` and searches this constant within that module. So if nesting is `[A::B, A]` and we're looking for the constant with token `C`, the interpreter will look for `A::B::C` first and then `A::C`.

However, in your example, that will fail in both cases :). Then the interpreter starts searching ancestors of the first (and only first) module in Module.nesting. `SubrExample.singleton_class.ancestors` gives you:

```
[
  #<Class:SubExample>,
  #<Class:SuperExample>,
  #<Class:Object>,
  #<Class:BasicObject>,
  Class,
  Module,
  Object,
  Kernel,
  BasicObject
]
```

As you can see - there is no `SuperExample` module, only its singleton class - which is why constant lookup within `class << self` fails (`print_constant_fails`).

The ancestors of `Subclass` are:

```
[
  SubExample,
  SuperExample,
  Object,
  Kernel,
  BasicObject
]
```

We have `SuperExample` there, so the interpreter will manage to find `SuperExample::A_CONSTANT` within this nesting.

We're left with `print_constant_works_2`. This is an instance method on a singleton class, so `self` within this method is just `SubExample`. So, we're looking for `SubExample::A_CONSTANT` - constant lookup firstly searches on `SubExample` and, when that fails, on all its ancestors, including `SuperExample`.

Comment: Something seems to be missing in the last sentence (after "when that fails"). What happens when it fails?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Ah, missing comas. Hopefully fixed now? Thanks for edit, I need to go back to learning proper english :P

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with scope. When you are inside `class << self`, the scope is different than when you are inside `class Something`. Thus, inside `class << self` there is actually no constant called `A_CONSTANT`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, every Ruby's constant has its own path, start from the main (root) with the sign `::` (default, we don't need to declare this sign). And `class` should not be considered a keyword (kind of static), but a method (kind of dynamic) take responsibility for creating a `class object` and a `class name constant` which point to that `class object`, and all `Constants` are defined inside a class without a path (P::Q::...) will automatically be considered belongs to the created class with path `:: ClassName::A_CONSTANT`.

```rb
GLOBAL = 1
class SuperExample
  A_CONSTANT = "super constant" # <-- ::SuperExample::A_CONSTANT
end

puts ::GLOBAL # 1
puts ::SuperExample # SuperExample
puts ::SuperExample::A_CONSTANT # "super constant"
```

It looks like constants paths in children classes has same level with parent

```rb
class SubExample < SuperExample
end
puts ::SubExample::A_CONSTANT # "super constant"
```

As I noticed, all constants (without `::`) inside the class block will be set path under the classpath, so when you get them, either you get with the explicitly constant path or under the class that constants belong to:

```rb
class SubExample < SuperExample
 def self.print_constant_works_1
  puts A_CONSTANT # ::SubExample::A_CONSTANT
 end

 def another
  puts A_CONSTANT # ::SubExample::A_CONSTANT
 end

 def yet_another
  puts SubExample::A_CONSTANT # ::SubExample::A_CONSTANT
 end
end
```

Now check `class << self`

```rb
class SubExample < SuperExample
 class << self
  puts self # <Class:SubExample>

  def print_constant_works_2
   puts self::A_CONSTANT # declare explicitly constant path
  end

  def print_constant_fails
   puts A_CONSTANT # not declare explicitly <-- Class:SubExample::A_CONSTANT
  end
 end
end
```

As you can see, the class inside `class << self` is different, so the path of constant `A_CONSTANT` inside method `print_constant_fails` is pointing to `Class:SubExample` which does not define any constant `A_CONSTANT`, so an error `uninitialized constant #<Class:SubExample>::A_CONSTANT` be raised.

Meanwhile `print_constant_works_2` will work since we declare explicitly constant path, and `self` in this case is actually `SubExample`(call `SubExample.print_constant_works_2`).

Now let try with an explicit path `::A_CONSTANT` inside `print_constant_fails`

```rb
def print_constant_fails
 puts ::A_CONSTANT
end
```

The error be raised is `uninitialized constant A_CONSTANT`, `::A_CONSTANT` is considered a global constant (main).

Comment: `class` is very strictly a keyword and cannot be used within the method (unlike Class.new). Subclasses do not "inherit" constants - they happen to resolve to the same constant, which might often be a source of errors. Constant `SubExample::A_CONSTANT` does not exist, but ruby interpeter resolves it to `SuperExample::A_CONSTANT` instead. Constants are not always set to live in the current module/class - constants defined within `Class.new` block are defined globally or acording to `Module.nesting`

Comment: `SubExample::A_CONSTANT` is the constant `path`, and you're right, i think i use word `inherit` incorrect in this case. @BroiSatse

Comment: Actually, the "path" is still `SuperExample::A_CONSTANT`. If you define a class `Inner` inside (to make use of Module#name) `SuperExample` you will notice that `SubExample::Inner` returns `SuperExample::Inner` class

Comment: One-space indent in Ruby code? Is that the standard? Perhaps Stefan Mischook [was right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLmocggLMj4&t=6m14s) after all?